# Why is this div tag visible when I have clearly made it hidden?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying an animation effect and the second animation effect is supposed to be delayed for two seconds. In this delay, the div tag should be hidden, but it is visible.

I will show you the two div tags first, followed by the css that I am using to make the animation.

HTML:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>        

 <div class="featuredprojectscontainer">
        <div id="firstad" class="slideDown" >


        </div><!-- end of first ad -->

        <div id="secondad" class="animationdelay invisible slideDown2">

        </div><!-- end of second ad -->

    </div><!-- end of featured projects container -->
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/* this is for the featured projects section */
.featuredprojectscontainer{
 width: 79%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 left: 30%;
}

#firstad{
background-color: #70c1b3;
width: 900px;
height: 209pt;
visibility: hidden;
}

#secondad{
margin-top: 13.333px;
width: 900px;
height: 223pt;
background-color: blue;
visibility: hidden;
}




/*
==============================================
slideDown
==============================================
*/

.animationdelay{
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-delay: 2s;
}

.invisible, .notvisible{
 visibility: hidden;
}


.slideDown{
 animation-name: slideDown;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideDown;

 animation-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

 animation-timing-function: ease;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

 visibility: visible !important;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
 0% {
     transform: translateY(-100%);
   }
 50%{
    transform: translateY(8%);
 }
 65%{
    transform: translateY(-4%);
 }
 80%{
    transform: translateY(4%);
 }
 95%{
    transform: translateY(-2%);
 }
100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
}
50%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(8%);
}
65%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
}
80%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4%);
}
95%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2%);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}


/*
==============================================
More delayed slideDown
==============================================
*/

.slideDown2{
animation-delay: 3s;
animation-delay: 2s, 4ms;
animation-name: slideDown2;
-webkit-animation-name: slideDown2;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-delay: 2s;

animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

visibility: visible !important;
}

@keyframes slideDown2 {
0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
50%{
    transform: translateY(8%);
}
65%{
    transform: translateY(-4%);
}
80%{
    transform: translateY(4%);
}
95%{
    transform: translateY(-2%);
}
100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideDown2 {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
}
50%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(8%);
}
65%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
}
80%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4%);
}
95%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2%);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

This can also be viewed on CodePen for easier readability: [click here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdYvGQ).

The blue box is supposed to be invisible until the animation forces it to drop down from the screen. But the box is visible and then it becomes invisible and drops down from the top. It's really confusing me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have `visibility: visible !important;` in `.slideDown2` which is overriding the `#secondad` rule

Answer (score 6):

In your CSS (line 122 in your codepen) you have called: `visibility: visible !important;`

The fact that it's located lower on the stylesheet and that it has a `!important` tag is causing it to overwrite your previous rule on line 17.

Removing the rule will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for reply to me Fritzypop. In the original files however, I should note that the keyframes are in a separate CSS file (animations.css) and the visibility is in the style.css file. The style.css file is linked first in the code, followed by the animations.css file. I tried doing what you recommended but it didn't work.

Any further recommendations?

Comment: I see, well I changed it up a little bit, instead of using `visibility`, I used `opacity`, and then I added the `animation-fill-mode` property to make sure the element would "stick" when done. Have a look at the fork: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grjYPG

Comment: You are awesome, thank you so much for this help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried to do that but they must have moved the option to somewhere else. Please help!

Answer (score 6):

It is because of css specificity

You have `visibility: visible !important;` in `.slideDown2` which is overriding the `#secondad` rule

Create a more specific rule to override it

```
#secondad.invisible{
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Arun! Thanks for the reply. I tried doing what you said, but it made the div tag completely invisible the whole time. I mentioned in my reply above that the keyframes are in a separate css file in my file structure. The keyframes are in animations.css while the #secondad tag is in the styles.css file. The styles.css file is linked first in the index file in question, followed by the animations.css. I'm not sure how the css rule of specificity is being applied here, but I can't just override one for the other at this point. So it seems.